# how to show vertical slider in [CodenameOne]

Tags: slider, codenameone

I want to show slider vertically in CodenameOne. Below is code which I tried to make it possible but still shows horizontally.

Code :

```
    Slider s1 = new Slider();
    Slider s2 = new Slider();
    s1.setVertical(true);
    s1.repaint();
    s2.setVertical(true);
    s2.repaint();
    findContMainT2O(f).add(BorderLayout.EAST, s1);
    findContMainT2O(f).add(BorderLayout.WEST, s2);
    findContMainT2O(f).repaint();
```

[see output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy8TS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more thing to do to make this work.

If you you look at the `Slider` and `SliderFull` styling, you could see that they have horizontal images. You will have to change this to vertical.

This is what I usually do if I want to reuse codename one slider images:

Go into my res folder and take the hd.png from these folders, depending on the theme you selected, In your case...

1. hd.png from `sliderBlueCenter` renamed to `sliderBlueCenterV`
2. hd.png from `sliderBlueLeft` renamed to `sliderBlueBottom`
3. hd.png from `sliderBlueRight` renamed to `sliderBlueTop`
4. hd.png from `sliderEmpty` renamed to `sliderEmptyCenter`
5. hd.png from `sliderEmptyLeft` renamed to `sliderEmptyBottom`
6. hd.png from `sliderEmptyRight` renamed to `sliderEmptyTop`

Then I rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise these copied and renamed images and using Image manipulation software like [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/) or Photoshop.

Now I open my theme.res and add this images using **Quick Add Multi Images** and selecting all of theme and choose **HD**.

The next thing is manipulating my current slider styling, I double click the `slider` and switch to `border` tab. Click the 3-dots and choose **Vertical Image** instead of **Horizontal Image**. Change your images to the added images appropriately.

Do the same for `SliderFull` then copy these 2 styles from `Unselected` and paste them into `Selected` and `Pressed` to override those.

Here is a [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5lbp7d29t65wx2/SliderAssets.zip?dl=1) to download slider images I manipulated earlier.

Comment: nice solution and worked too... just for knowledge purpose i want to ask you how is SliderFull is get considered ?, because i can map Slider in uiid not SliderFull.

Comment: If your Slider UIID is `SliderRed`, the `SliderFull` would be `SliderRedFull`